# Java/Groovy How do I correctly compare two string values? .equals() not working

Tags: java, groovy

Ok, this is driving me nuts.
I'm not too savvy with Java/Groovy but please point me to the right direction!

I have a GET call with response text like "["a","b","c"]"

I finally got it to arraylist to iterate through to compare strings.
I tried .equals(), .equalsIgnoreCase(), compareTo(), Objects.equals() etc. It does not match. I get "String not the same".
What am I missing?

```
def sb= new StringBuffer();
def rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

def line;
while((line=rd.readLine()) !=null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

//sb = "["a","b","c"]"

List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sb.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").split(",")));
int count = 0;
String strToFind= "a";

for (String iT : tempList){
    if (strToFind.equals(iT)){
        log.debug("\nString the same\n");
    } else {
        log.debug("\nString not the same\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That means they're not equal. Use your debugger, or print the strings and their length, to find out why.

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to have "invisible" characters in your string that throws off the compare.  So print out the `byte array` of each `string` to see for certain what they are.

Comment: In Groovy, `==` means `equals` (except null-safe). I also recommend looking at a tutorial on Groovy functional/pipeline style: it seems like you're doing a whole bunch of stuff by hand (wrapping, iterators, etc.) that just needs a `.filter` or a `.*`.

Comment: Thanks, Just as @WJS suggested, I printed out byte and yep, there was that doublequate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because the String you try to match has quotes.. so you are doing 
a == "a" which is not the same.. if you don't want to use your debugger to validate what I said try to compare their lengths ( or print them ). the answer applies for this String sb = "["a","b","c"]" which was feeded to the InputStreamReader the same way you provided it.

```java
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]".getBytes())));
```

Comment: Also, it's possible that this should just be run through a JSON parser like `JSONSlurper` or Jackson.

Comment: Well yes but the specific is just an array of strings. it cant be counted as a json cause its not key:value formatted

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed found that double quote. I had log.debug everywhere but didn't catch that because I assumed it meant string.

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis It's absolutely valid JSON. It's a JSON array with string values.

Comment: I literally did not thought of that xD. You are right @chrylis